Colors gone from preview in texstudio
For some reason (possibly after a recent update), all images in TeXStudio are showing up as black and white. However, the output PDF files do retain the colorful images when I view them with a PDF viewer.
How to fix this? I am using Kubuntu 24.04.
I installed texstudio from the official repositories, and it was working fine until recently (I updated the system sometime ago, but did not perform any other changes).

When I run texstudio in the terminal, there is no error message (no message at all), and the app opens.
